# Styled component with link not open page

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Hi guys I have a react component below that must open a link to a click on a styled component, but the click does not refresh the page at the new link even if the link is displayed in the search bar

**React Code:**

```
/* eslint-disable */
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Element = ({ el }) => {
  return el?.url ? (
    <Container to={el.url}>
      <div className={`sidenav-el ${el.current ? 'current' : ''}`}>
        <div className="img-container">
          <img src={el.img} />
        </div>
        <span className="title">{el.title}</span>
      </div>
    </Container>
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
};

export default Element;

const Container = styled(Link)`
  color: var(--cMain);
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover {
    color: var(--cMain);
  }

  .sidenav-el {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10% 0;
    position: relative;

    .img-container {
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
      width: 70%;
      border: 2px solid var(--cMain);

      img {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    span {
      display: block;
      font-size: 1rem;
      margin-top: 0.5rem;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    &.current {
      .img-container::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 5px solid var(--cMain);
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: try inspecting and see the link...You may also need to change it to `to={${el.url}}`...add backtics around `${el.url}`

Comment: your solutions give me this error: SyntaxError: /Users/riccardo/Desktop/Progetti/Personali/frontendrisolvereiproblemi/src/components/Sidebar/Element.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "}" (7:20)

   5 | const Element = ({ el }) => {
   6 |   return el?.url ? (
>  7 |     <Container to={${el.url}}>
     |                     ^
   8 |       <div c

Comment: you have to add `` around `${el.url}` ... also console.log to see if you're actually getting the link